# Make a div on top of all the others

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a searchbar in my navbar, and when you type something inside it, another div below it appears with results according to your typing,

I want to put this div above all of the others, because for now the div with the results goes under the website content...

I tried to put a "z-index: 999" on it, but nothing changes,

**To test it**
- Go on the films page of my website : https://ofilms.herokuapp.com/films
- Click on the "search" icon in the navbar
- Type "Avengers"
- See the results div going under the other div

Comment: Try adding ```position: absolute``` as well.

Comment: @NikhilGoyal It looks like it changes nothing... am I forced to use this ? because I don't want it in absolute if possible..

Comment: As per my understanding, ```z-index``` will work only with position as absolute or fixed. Maybe you can try giving relative as well. But not sure whether it will work or not. To be frank, I have never tried that.

Comment: ok it works perfectly now thank you, make an answer and i'll accept it :)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: the problem description is clear i think, because someone answered it in a minute.. and a link to the deployed website allows to show directly the issue instead of creating a jsfiddle or what.. and the code is the "z-index: 999" i put in the description..

Comment: If your page ever goes down, this post is completely useless to the posterity and may as well be deleted if you found your answer. A MVCE ensures that the problem is isolated and applicable to more scenarios than just the specific one you've found yourself in. The speed at which someone answered (Especially because this problem is incredibly simple) is not an indicator on how good you did as an asker. Ic annot replicate your issue with the code `z-index: 999`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: absolute` to your CSS.

As per my understanding, z-index will only work with position as `absolute` or `fixed`. I have never tried with position as `relative`. We can experiment that as well. :-)

Comment: z-index works on any `position`'ed element, regardless of the position value (not only `absolute`, `fixed`).

Comment: Looks like it works for any value other than static. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Thanks for updating. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but you could try giving the **! important** parameter too:

```
z-index: 99 !important;
```